# How do i download archive with static assets to my server and replace all "https://vuu.io" links with my own using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, url, static, assets

WHITE-LABEL STATIC ASSETS

All links to static content in fax report are hardcoded to Vuu.io, but you may replace them with your own URL.
In this case you'll need to download archive with static assets to your own server and replace all "https://vini.az" links.

Download static assets: https://vuu.i0/fax.zip

How can I achieve this using wordpress?

I have uploaded static assets on my server but cant find where do replace the url

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace all occurrences of a certain URL in your database, I would personally use the [WP CLIs](https://wp-cli.org/) [search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) command.

Example use case would be something like this:

```bash
wp search-replace 'https://old-url.com' 'https://new-url.com'
```